# pyvenv-3.4 pip freeze showing multiple packages in new environment

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am using pyvenv-3.4 on Ubuntu 12.04 and just created my first virtual environment.

After activating i checked to see that no packages had been installed using pip freeze and found the following list of packages..

```
Brlapi==0.5.6
GnuPGInterface==0.3.2
Mako==0.5.0
MarkupSafe==0.15
PAM==0.4.2
PIL==1.1.7
Twisted-Core==11.1.0
Twisted-Names==11.1.0
Twisted-Web==11.1.0
adium-theme-ubuntu==0.3.2
apt-xapian-index==0.44
apturl==0.5.1ubuntu3
argparse==1.2.1
chardet==2.0.1
command-not-found==0.2.44
configglue==1.0
debtagshw==0.1
defer==1.0.2
dirspec==3.0.0
duplicity==0.6.18
httplib2==0.7.2
jockey==0.9.7
keyring==0.9.2
language-selector==0.1
launchpadlib==1.9.12
lazr.restfulclient==0.12.0
lazr.uri==1.0.3
louis==2.3.0
nvidia-common==0.0.0
oauth==1.0.1
onboard==0.97.1
oneconf==0.2.8.1
pexpect==2.3
piston-mini-client==0.7.2
protobuf==2.4.1
pyOpenSSL==0.12
pycrypto==2.4.1
pycups==1.9.61
pycurl==7.19.0
pyinotify==0.9.2
pyserial==2.5
pysmbc==1.0.13
python-apt==0.8.3ubuntu7.2
python-dateutil==1.5
python-debian==0.1.21ubuntu1
python-virtkey==0.60.0
pyxdg==0.19
reportlab==2.5
rhythmbox-ubuntuone==4.2.0
screen-resolution-extra==0.0.0
sessioninstaller==0.0.0
simplejson==2.3.2
software-center-aptd-plugins==0.0.0
stevedore==0.15
system-service==0.1.6
ubuntuone-couch==0.3.0
ubuntuone-installer==3.0.2
ubuntuone-storage-protocol==3.0.2
ufw==0.31.1-1
unattended-upgrades==0.1
unity-lens-video==0.3.5
unity-scope-video-remote==0.3.5
usb-creator==0.2.23
vboxapi==1.0
virtualenv==1.11.4
virtualenv-clone==0.2.4
virtualenvwrapper==4.2
wadllib==1.3.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
xdiagnose==2.5.3
xkit==0.0.0
zope.interface==3.6.1
```

As this is a new activated environment why would i see the list of packages already installed in Ubuntu?

Apologies if i am missing something obvious but i expected this to be empty.

Any insight would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the latest version of virtualenv, `--no-site-packages` isn't necessary anymore. I highly recommend not relying on python modules from aptitude :).

You can also do `pip freeze --local > requirements.txt` This will output only the packages installed into your `virtual env`, without listing all dependencies (the packages themselves, handle those.)

**UPDATE**

`pyenv` is problematic, that's why you are getting extra packages in `requirements.txt`. 
You can remove `pyenv` and install latest version of `virtualenv` and ask `virtualenv` to create the `env` for you by this command.

```
sudo virtualenv --no-site-packages -p /usr/bin/python3.4 <envname>
```